# Update a HTML table record via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a form with only three inputs, a HTML table and a submit button

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="inputText1" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText2" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText3" required>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

that works this way: 
every time the user clicks the submit button the HTML table adds to its rows the value of the inputs via jQuery + two linkbuttons and the variable cont specified as a number in a hidden element in order to easily locate the row when it comes to update it.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var cont=0;
            $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                cont++;
                var id = $("#inputText1").val().toLowerCase();
                var lastname = $("#inputText2").val();
                var name = $("#inputText3").val();


                if (checkId(lastname)) {
                    return alert('El ID ya ha sido especificado');
                }

                $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td for="id">' + id + '</td><td for="lastname">' + lastname + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td id="cont" style="visibility:hidden">' + cont + '</td><td><a href="#" id="select">Modificar</a><a href="#" id="eliminar">  Eliminar</a></td></tr>');
                $("#inputText1").val('');
                $("#inputText2").val('');
                $("#inputText3").val('');
                $('#inputText1').focus();

            });
            });
```

the submit button works OK the problem is when I want to modify a row, what I do now is to populate the inputs with the values of the row selected in order to let the user to modify its content but I cannot retrieve the value of the variable cont that represents an specific and different number for each row and besides of that I don't know how to update the table's row once the user decide to update the record, could you please help me, this is the jQuery code I had for the moment

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#myTable").on('click', '#select', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

             //var contador= currentRow.$("#cont").val();
             //alert(contador);
             //doesn't retrieve neither show anything

            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
            var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); 
            var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); 
            $("#inputText1").val(col1);
            $("#inputText2").val(col2);
            $("#inputText3").val(col3);
        });
    });
```

and also would like to dd that when the user add the info from the inputs to the table, theres a gap where the hidden field is

[image]

how could I solve this?

Comment: Can you click the submit button multiple times? You're appending a bunch of elements using `.append` but you're using a hard-coded ID for all of them... if you click the button more than once, you're going to have non-unique ID's, which is a major no-no. Not to say that's the root cause here, but certainly should be cleaned up. Also, your var `contador` should probably be `var contador = currentRow.find("#cont").val();` - though again, `#cont` is one of those appended elements that there could potentially be multiple of, though it seems only one in each row. Still should be a class instead.

Comment: I just add modificication to the var contador as you specified but still nothing appears in the alert(contador) and could youplease tell me how to modify the non unique ID's ?

Comment: Change them to classes, and reference them by using `.` instead of `#`. Like I said though, I am not saying that's definitely the cause here - merely pointing it out.